# I'm having an "Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)". Where is my error?

Tags: java

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterGrade

{

public static void main(String[] args)

{

```
char grade;

String input;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter grade awarded");

input = keyboard.nextLine();

grade = input.charAt(0);

switch (grade)

{

  case 'A':

    System.out.println("Grade was between " + 89.5 - 100);

    break;

  case 'B':

    System.out.println("Grade was between " + 79.5 - 89.45); 

    break;

  case 'C':

    System.out.println("Grade was between " + 69.5 - 79.49);

    break;

  case 'D':

    System.out.println("Grade was between " + 59.5 - 69.49);

    break;

  case 'F':

    System.out.println("Grade was below " + 59.5); 

    break;  

    System.out.println("Invalid grade inputted ");

}
```

}

}

4 errors found:
File: C:\Users\Raj\Downloads\Java\LetterGrade.java  [line: 19]
Error: The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, int
File: C:\Users\Raj\Downloads\Java\LetterGrade.java  [line: 22]
Error: The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, double
File: C:\Users\Raj\Downloads\Java\LetterGrade.java  [line: 25]
Error: The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, double

I fixed the big errors i had, sorry about that. I really wasn't thinking straight and I understand i need to read more, which i will be doing tonight, but I'm have a different error now.

Comment: `Any other character;` that's not Java... at all.

Comment: Your code is full of silly typos. `next.Int();` is wrong. Fix these errors and come back.

Comment: It appears you lack a very fundamental understanding on the constructs you are using. There's semicolons where there shouldn't be, and your `case` keywords need to be lowercased.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

**1.** `grade = keyboard.next.Int();` should be `grade = keyboard.nextInt();`
**2.** `Case A;`

- a. `Case` should be `case`
- b. What is `A` you switch an `int` but there is no variable `A` that
  holds any `int` value. Also if you mean the `char` `A` the you should
  change it to `'A'`
- You need a `:` instead of `;`after `case`. So something like `case 'A':`

**3.** `switch (grade);` remove the `;`. Change it to `switch (grade)`

**4.** Not sure about this `Any other character;` Hopefully its meant to be a comment

Comment: I changed to char, and now I'm having a new error that I'm unsure of.

Comment: And you want me to guess what that might be? Update the questions with the expected output and what output you are specifically getting

Answer (score 1):

**First Issue**:

```
grade = keyboard.next.Int();
```

change to

```
grade = keyboard.nextInt();
```

**Second Issue**:

your The switch Statement is clearly wrong

for example

1. `switch (grade); <--- wrong 
       {`
2. `Case A; <--- wrong`
3. your `grade` is type `int` but your case has type `char`
4. `Case` in wrong, you should have `case`

Look at this sample as your **blue print**

```
public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int month = 8;
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
    }
}
```

[Source of Code and Read more about Switch Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll visit the oracle website more often for any problems!

Answer (score 0):

There should not be a semi-colon at the end of line 13.  (The "switch" line).

Once you have fixed that, you will then see that the syntax of the "case" clauses is wrong.

And "any other character" is nonsense from the Java perspective.  (I'm surprised that the Java compiler didn't throw a house-brick at you!)

---

> I'm not sure what's wrong with what I'm doing.

You are trying to write Java without bothering to learn it properly.  That is wrong on many levels.

I recommend that you read the Oracle Java Tutorial.  For this example, read the [Switch Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) page.

Comment: Okay i know that was completely wrong. Haha. I didn't know how to set an input for other cases to show "Invalid grade inputted"

Comment: Hey Stephen, i read the page you linked, it helped me a lot. I'm getting a different error now.

Comment: Why are you trying to subtract `89.45` from `79.5`?  (That is what you have written!)  In fact, the compilation error happens because `"Grade was between " + 79.5` is a string concatenation, and then you are trying to subtract `89.45` from a string.

Comment: Lmfao, i realized that i fixed it. I'm still learning as I go =/